# Generate all combinations from 4 columns but remove results where a value occurs more than once in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, combinations

I spent hours learning Google sheets and still can't put things together to solve this problem. I have the formula for generating all combinations but can't seem to remove the duplicate text from each cell. Here's an example sheet. [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DSRplGW4ICwDt9B4n3pSX9d1tImHx52qXMy2f4RoM0w/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Tried combinations of many functions that didn't work. It could be syntax errors.

Comment: Can you **manually** add the *expected result* for your test data?!

Comment: Your provided sample sheet doesn't make any sense to us.

Comment: Your question needs to stand on its own. All the information about your scenario, data and requirements needs to be included in your question. Please do not expect that users must/will/should/could open your spreadsheet in order to better understand your question.

Comment: I thought the expected results were clear as written even without opening the spreadsheet. Tom Sharpe understood and offered a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what I think you mean, you could try this:

```
=let(perms,
INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(D2:D, D2:D<>"")))),
filter(perms,byrow(perms,lambda(r,countunique(split(r," "))=counta(split(r," "))))))
```

[image]

You could put other condtions on which combinations to select, e.g. for Frank no more than twice and Mary no more than 3 times:

```
=let(perms,
INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(D2:D, D2:D<>"")))),
filter(perms,byrow(perms,lambda(r,let(split,split(r," "),(countif(split,"Frank")<=2)*(countif(split,"Mary")<=3))))))
```

I have chosen to use an inner 'let' to avoid repetition but it doesn't actually save much.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Just what I was asking. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this solution if you can help. What if I wanted to remove the results that contain an item that appears more than a stated number of times? Ex. So, in the unfiltered column E above, results where Frank appears more than twice are removed. Results where Mary occurs more than 3 times are removed.

Comment: Will add to my answer.